Is a localization of a local ring local?
I'm trying to answer the following question: " If $R$ is a local ring and $S$ a multiplicative set, is $S^{-1}R$ a local ring?"
I found out in this other question that a localization is local iff the saturation of the multiplicative set is the complement of a prime ideal.
Given this proposition, i tried searching for a local ring with a saturated multiplicative set that is not the complement of a prime, but i failed. Can someone help me? Thanks a lot!

Hi, welcome to the site. I suggest you ask your two questions (about the general criterion for when $S^{-1}R$ would be local) and "whether or not $S^{-1}R$ must be local for a local $R$" separately

@FShrike Thanks for the suggestion, i found a proof of the general criterion here

I don't know the answer to your question about local rings in general (I suspect the answer is, "no") but it is true for discrete valuation rings at least. If $S$ is saturated and $R$ is a DVR, $S^{-1}R$ can only be $R$ itself or $\mathrm{Frac}(R)$; both local. I imagine if you look at more complicated valuation rings that this would be false

I found out the answer is no, here's why:
First of all, given a ring $R$, the complement of a union of prime ideals is a multiplicative saturated set.
In fact, if $\mathscr{P}$ is a collection of prime ideals and $ S = R \setminus \bigcup_{P\in \mathscr{P}} P $, then
$$xy\in S \iff xy\notin P \quad \forall P\in I \iff x,y\notin P \quad \forall P\in I \\\iff x,y\in S \qquad \qquad \forall x,y\in R$$
where the middle equivalence holds because $P$ is an ideal ($\to$), and it's prime ($\gets$).

To build a counterexample we need to localize a local ring by the complement of two primes $P_1$ and $P_2$ such that neither $P_1$ is contained in $P_2$ nor viceversa.
An example can be $\mathbb{K}[x,y]$ localized at $S$, the complement of the prime $I=(x,y)$ (the ideal of polynomials with zero constant term). So the local ring is $R = S^{-1}\mathbb{K}[x,y]$. This ring has one maximal ideal $S^{-1}I$ of height $2$ and many primes of height $1$, such as $P_1 = S^{-1}(x)$ and $P_2 = S^{-1}(y)$.
So by our first proposition $T = R \setminus (P_1 \cup P_2)$ is a saturated multiplicative set, and this criterion proves that $T^{-1}R$ is not a local ring.
